# Console.Log is not executed when inside the RXJS Tap operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have the following observables:

```
this.authenticationService.isSignedIn() -> Observable<Boolean>

this.user$ -> Observable<UserModel>
```

I need to check a condition based on both so I tried:

```
zip(this.authenticationService.isSignedIn(), this.user$).pipe(
  map(([isSignedIn, user]: [boolean, UserModel]) => isSignedIn && user.claims))
);
```

Because I am getting an unexpected result I tried to check things out using:

```
zip(this.authenticationService.isSignedIn(), this.user$).pipe(
  tap(([isSignedIn, user]: [boolean, UserModel]) => {
    console.log(isSignedIn);
    console.log(user);
  })
);
```

But the two `console.log` are not executed. What am I missing?

Comment: You should use `combineLatest` if you want to evaluate the observable for at least one of the observable emits a new value. `zip` will emit value only if ALL the observables emits the value.

Comment: it seems here zip is exactly what author needs. signedIn and user streams seems to be changing at the same moment. so zip fits perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could be missing a subscribtion. All rxjs things are lazy and won't be running untill a subscription is done. if you don't need to handle the result somehow else except for your `tap` operator, just add `.subscribe()` in the end

```
zip(...).pipe(
  tap(...)
).subscribe();
```